# How to generate a color histogram in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a texture2d in unity and I want to generate a color histogram based on each pixel's hue value. I've tried using getPixels but it's insanely slow for a 1920x1080 texture.

```
if (tex == null)
{
    return null;
}
tex = GetComponent<GUITexture>().texture as Texture2D;
Color32[] texColors = tex.GetPixels32();
int total = texColors.Length;

int[] Harray = new int[360];
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    float H;
    float S;
    float V;

    Color.RGBToHSV(new Color(texColors[i].r, texColors[i].g, texColors[i].b),out H,out S,out V);
    Harray[(int)H]++;
}


for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
{
    PlotManager.Instance.PlotAdd("Hue", Harray[i]);
}
```

I'm thinking shader might be able to help but I've no experience at shader programming. Can a shader populates the hue occurrence array and return it while maintaining a good frame rate?

Comment: really Unity is just not built for anything vaguely like this.  it's just not what it's for.  you might as well set about trying to do bone animations in native iOS, you know?  I suggest you get NatCam from the asset store, and contact the makers of that package about a native plugin for this need.

Comment: @JoeBlow Do you work for NatCam? Or just a big fan? All of the StackOverflow posts I see have you recommending it - considering buying it and battling to find a second opinion ;)

Comment: hey @EvanKnowles !  obviously I do not work for NatCam. it's a miracle someone finally released a proper camera package, since Unity essentially has no camera software yet.  its a case of "everyone uses it" - much like say AntiCheatToolKit or Vectrosity.  It would be 6-12 man-months of work to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

There's an asset on unity store uses compute shader with a RWStructuredBuffer to achieve this : https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15699